# Is there any way to print white colour onto paper?

Tags: printing, ink

I want to print the colour white onto a transfer paper.

Comment: This is a similar question to this one and may have useful information for you: https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/image-transferred-onto-black-fabric/3134#3134

Comment: Actually, I need to print all white... so yeah.

Comment: Unless you have white ink in your printer, it's impossible. There's no way to make white out of Cyan, Yellow, Magenta, and Black. If you buy a special printer that holds white ink cartridges, you can print white.

Answer (score 4):

There is white Trace-it transfer paper from a company called ScratchArt. This would require you to print out your image first then trace over image to make the actual image transfer.

Similar to the idea of carbon paper instead in this case the paper is coated on one side with lose layer of white ink bound with wax. The image is transferred by placing the coated side down gently onto a surface and then scribing the image on the non coated surface.

Answer (score 4):

**- Method 1 -**

The fastest and smartest way is, set color as RGB(0,0,1).
But if you want to print white color permanetly and **want to white color** following method 2

**- Method 2 -**

You will not get anything on the paper with a basic CMYK inkjet or laser printer. The CMYK color mixing is subtractive, meaning that it requires the base that is being colored to have all colors (i.e., White) So that it can create color variation through subtraction:

```
White - Cyan - Yellow = Green
White - Yellow - Magenta = Red
White - Cyan - Magenta = Blue
```

White is represented as 0 cyan, 0 yellow, 0 magenta, and 0 black - effectively, 0 ink for a printer that simply has those four cartridges. This works great when you have white media, as "printing no ink" simply leaves the white exposed, but as you can imagine, this doesn't work for non-white media.

If you don't have a base color to subtract from (i.e., Black), then it doesn't matter what you subtract from it, you still have the color Black.

As others are pointing out, there are special printers which can operate in the CMYW color space, or otherwise have a white ink or toner. These can be used to print light colors on top of dark or otherwise non-white media.

You might also find my answer to a different question about color spaces helpful or informative.

REF : https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-print-white-onto-black-paper